# Is there a way to avoid multiple nested select in this case?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of all the options products may have like this (1 product can have many options):
products_id     options_id

Now I need to selection all products_ids that have **ALL** 3 options 1,2,3 then I have to do something like this

```
select products_id 
from options 
where products_id in 
     (select products_id 
      from options 
      where products_id in 
              (select products_id 
               from options 
               where options_id = 3) 
      and options_id = 2)
and options_id = 1
```

This seems to be very ineffective if I have to do with say 10 options. And I wonder if there is a way to get around all this

Edit:
I'm putting some sample data as requested:

```
products_id           options_id
1                     1
1                     2
1                     3
1                     4
1                     5
2                     1
2                     2
2                     3
3                     2
3                     3
3                     9
4                     1
4                     2
4                     8
```

If we use my above sql, we should get only products 1,2 which have ALL options 1,2,3. The others (3,4) do not have all the required options

Comment: Could you provide structure of `options`  table? I'm just trying to get how your query could return more then 0 rows. Seriously :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to post the table data here, but I will put some sample data on the question so you can see. Note that 1 product can have multiple options.

Comment: `Note that 1 product can have multiple options` - ok, then try this `select distinct products_id from options where options_id = 1 AND options_id = 2 AND options_id = 3 `

Comment: @aleksey.berezan it wont work, see my sample data and you will know why.

Comment: Try this `select products_id
from (select distinct * from options) t
where t.options_id in (1,2,3) -- change here
group by t.products_id
having COUNT(*) = 3 -- change here`

Comment: @aleksey.berezan: this is actually quite nice and fast, I will do some more testing

Comment: I may have to redo many more tests but so far the nested selects method is still the fatest *_*

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursive function and keep one field "parent_id" in the table to locate all the related products

Comment: can you please elaborate this? The parent_id is for the products_id or?

Comment: i mean if your requirement is like to fetch all related products for a particular product then such field can be added in the product table itself and a recursive function can be used at script level.

Comment: I see. My requirement is to fetch all products have all the options though. For example, you may want to look for shirts that are yellow and made from cotton and have size XL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use or operator with select distinct:

```
select distinct products_id from options where options_id = 1 OR options_id = 2 OR options_id = 3
```

Edit:
Answer above is obviously wrong. But i think grouping by products and then checking the count will solve the problem.

```
SELECT products_id FROM (SELECT products_id, count(*) AS cnt FROM options WHERE options_id = 1 OR options_id = 2 OR options_id = 3 GROUP BY products_id) WHERE cnt = 3
```

Comment: I tested this and it seems to return more records than expected. I think the issue here is that we want to have products that must contain ALL options, not just either 1 of the 3

Comment: Then maybe: SELECT products_id FROM (SELECT products_id, count(*) AS cnt FROM options WHERE options_id = 1 OR options_id = 2 OR options_id = 3 GROUP BY products_id) WHERE cnt = 3

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`You can try the following select statement:

```
Select Products_Id from Options Where Options_id IN(1,2,3)
```

if all of your data are in the same table.

if you want to select products from the product table which as options_id = 1/2/3 in the options table you can use the following

```
Select field1, field2, * from products where products_id in (Select Products_Id from options where options_id IN(1,2,3))
```

Let's say your tables are created as follow:
Products ( product_id, product#, description, color, ....)
Options( option_id, Name, description, ....)
Options_for_Products(product_Id, Option_id)

You can use the sub queries as follow:

```
Select * from products where product_id IN(Select Product_id from Options_for_Products Where Option_Id IN (Select Option_Id from Options where Name='whatevernameyouwant')) // get product using option name.

Select Product_Id FROM Options_for_Products where Option_Id IN(Select Option_Id from Options where Name='whatevernameyouwant') // getting product_id from Options_for_Products using option name.

Select Product_Id from Options_for_Products where Option_id IN(1,2,3) // this is what you asked for. using option ID.
```

and if you want to select Product_id that must have all three conditions then instead of using "Option_id IN(1,2,3)" you have to separate them in 3 different ditional AND statements like this: `Select Products_Id FROM Options Where Products_Id IN(Select Products_id from Option Where Options_id = 1) AND Product_ID IN(Select Products_Id from Options where options_id = 2) AND Products_Id IN(Select Products_id from Options where options_id = 3)`

Comment: Thank you, my mistake for not clarifying that the product must contain ALL 3 options, not just either one. I have updated my question to include that. So I think in this case IN may not work?

Comment: yes, the IN case will not work.  Let me think of another way for you to be able to use N number of options w/o having to worry rewrite the query each time a new option id is needed.

Comment: check my other solution below and see if that works out for you.

Comment: Yes your last select in does yield the same result (distinct is needed), seems to be 10 time slower (with 2 options). I will see if this performance gap may decrease if we query for more options restriction, say 10.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a MS SQL, there's a split() function laying around out there somewhere.

create that function and do the following steps.  I'm not going to write the SQL Codes, just give you the idea of getting to it.

Create a store procedure named GetProductIdsForOptions that has a single input parameter, let's say @OptionIds of type nvarchar(whateverlenght you want), this will be a comma separated value string

Create a tempt table (create table #table1 syntax). to contain the splitted options_Id

insert into #table1 select distinct value from dbo.split(@optionIds,',')

create another tempt table to contain the products_id and the options_id

insert into #table2 select distinct products_id, options_id from Options Where Options_id IN(select optionId from #table1)

then

Select Products_id from #table2 Group By Products_id Having count(options_id) = (Select count(*) from #table1)

Queries has not been tested.  This is just an idea of how to go around it.

Comment: interesting though I'm using mysql, I will see if mysql does allow something like this.